# GridPane add() does not set column span

Tags: java, javafx, gridpane

I have a little project in JavaFX. I'm trying to build a GridPane and I want to add a ChoiceBox, with a column span. I'd want to be large like the first one, but seems like something is not good.

```
    public class Main extends Application  implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

    Label sol=new Label();
    TextField ca=new TextField(),
            cb=new TextField();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));

        ChoiceBox localitateBox = new ChoiceBox();
        ArrayList listStrings = new ArrayList();
        listStrings.add("TEST CHOICE BOX 1");
        listStrings.add("TEST CHOICE BOX 2");
        localitateBox.getItems().addAll(listStrings);
        grid.add(localitateBox, 0, 0);

        TextField numeText =new TextField();
        numeText.setPromptText("Name");
        grid.add(numeText,1,0);

        ChoiceBox functionBox = new ChoiceBox();
        functionBox.getItems().add("Add");
        functionBox.getItems().add("Print");
        functionBox.getItems().add("Info");


        grid.add(functionBox,0,1,3,1);


        Scene scena = new Scene(grid, 500, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scena);
        primaryStage.setTitle("TEST");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    }
}
```

I'll attach a screen of the output.
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aO0Fm.png)

Comment: What have you done to set the column-span?

Answer (score 0):

When working with `Gridpane` in pure code, you should show the gridlines. This will help you while creating the `GridPane`. **The gridlines should only be used for debugging and not in your production code!**

It looks like you don't need to use `column-span`. You need to make sure the `ChoiceBox` covers the width. Use `setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>
{

    Label sol = new Label();
    TextField ca = new TextField();
    TextField cb = new TextField();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setGridLinesVisible(true);
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));

        ChoiceBox localitateBox = new ChoiceBox();
        ArrayList listStrings = new ArrayList();
        listStrings.add("TEST CHOICE BOX 1");
        listStrings.add("TEST CHOICE BOX 2");
        localitateBox.getItems().addAll(listStrings);
        grid.add(localitateBox, 0, 0);

        TextField numeText = new TextField();
        numeText.setPromptText("Name");
        grid.add(numeText, 1, 0);

        ChoiceBox functionBox = new ChoiceBox();
        functionBox.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        functionBox.getItems().add("Add");
        functionBox.getItems().add("Print");
        functionBox.getItems().add("Info");

        grid.add(functionBox, 0, 1);

        Scene scena = new Scene(grid, 500, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scena);
        primaryStage.setTitle("TEST");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent)
    {

    }
}
```

[image]

Just an added note: I recommend against `implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>` if you are learning `JavaFX`. It works but leads to confusion, in my opinion.